# How would I convert old format haarcascades into the new format XML

Tags: opencv

I have an old format haarcascade: `haarcascade_mcs_nose.xml` (it ships with Open CV)

I either want:

- It converted to the new format XML
- OR to be able to open it like it was a new format XML (i.e. in the internal data structure `featureEvaluator` NULL and `oldCasscade` not NULL)

Is this possible?

There is a [similar question](http://answers.opencv.org/question/15083/convert-old-haarcascade-file-to-new-cascade/) on the CV forums but the answer is uses the `oldCasscade` structure which is not what I want.

Comment: Can you not just write a program to convert it?

Comment: Good suggestion but I don't know enough about the formats to write a converter.  It could be a massive headache.  I would have though someone has tacked this issue already.